# Need help to show green/red color text in .txt file written by a tcl script

Tags: colors, tcl, expect

I am using an `Expect` code which works in below fashion, i am trying to see the text written inside the file in green color for "passed" and red for word "failed". I tried the below ascii style but of no use. Can some one please guide me if it is possible to see the color text in a .txt file. I use Fedora 16, VI editor and a relevant version of TCL.

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

set text " Passed "
set data "\033\[00;32m $text \033\[0m\n";  # <---- THIS LINE
set filename "test.txt"
set fileId [open $filename "w"]
puts -nonewline $fileId $data
close $fileId
```

Comment: I do not want to use tk, I would also like to know if I could try editor other than vi

Comment: Works fine for me when I display it with `cat`

Comment: The color codes are interpreted by the terminal unless special effort is taken to prevent it. Text editors like _vi_ take that effort.

Comment: `less` doesn't display them either (but `more` does)

Comment: @Johannes Thank you so much, i would try it with cat command also.

Comment: @Donal Thank you for the suggestion. I meant to say that when I use that code  " set data "\033\[00;32m $text \033\[0m\n"  to display the color text on the terminal it just works fine , but i am trying to write some text it into a .txt file and want to see that text in color when I Open it. Would java package or Notepad++ or Komodo be useful for this task?

Comment: @code_trot The short answer: No. :-) Text editors as a rule try very hard to prevent that sort of thing. Text editors specialized for handling computer programs often have their own highlighting rules so that things like strings, comments and keywords get distinctive colors.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn `less` does, if you pass the `-R` option…

Comment: @Donal Thank you so much for the guidance.. :-) and BTW please tell me where I can learn about "less" and "-R " options. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to generate a file with coloured text that can be displayed independently of the Tcl program which generates it, how about generating a .pdf ?

You could use the [Pdf4Tcl](http://pdf4tcl.berlios.de/) package to generate a pdf file from your Tcl script, setting the text, colours and other formatting you want.  This file could then be opened in adobe reader or another pdf viewer, showing your coloured text.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Will try this and let you guys know.

Comment: I downloaded and tried to install the Pdf4tcl08 package in my Fedora 12, but it is not getting installed, any idea why this happens? Since this is not installed, i am getting package not found error.